# Access pass-through query giving error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the following code to run a passthrough query.  I'm trying to run the passthrough query, then check how many records are returned to figure out if it worked.  But I get an error saying

> "Invalid Operation"

Why is it doing this and how can I correct?

```
  Dim Item As String
  Item = InputBox("Enter Item needing a surrogate UPC.", "Enter Item")


Set db = CurrentDb

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("spAL_AssignSurrogateUPC")
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
qdf.SQL = "spAL_AssignSurrogateUPC '" & Item & "'"
With qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)       '<--- Error triggered here.
    If qdf.RecordCount = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Surrogate UPC assigned."
    Else
        MsgBox "ERROR.  Could not assign surrogate UPC."
    End If
End With
```

Comment: does spAL_AssignSurrogateUPC  return rows?

Comment: @ConradFrix -If it works it returns 1 row, if it doesn't work it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the EXEC syntax

```
qdf.SQL = "EXEC spAL_AssignSurrogateUPC '" & Replace(Item, "'", "''") & "';"
```

(I assume it's SQL Server.)

I also added a replace function in order to cope with single quotes in the `Item` string. This also helps prevent SQL injections.

---

EDIT:

Try to do this, instead of using the With-statement

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset

...

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "ERROR.  Could not assign surrogate UPC."
Else
    MsgBox "Surrogate UPC assigned."
End If
```

Comment: And the replace won't compile.

Comment: Sorry, you are using VBA, not VB.NET. It changed it.

Comment: I also added another way of testing the result of the query. See my edit.